# Craft Forum/Community options

Tags: users

Im curious to hear more about what any of you are using to build "community"/ "forum" messaging options into your craft cms site.

From what I've found it seems there would be a couple of interesting options

**Socialize Plugin** https://dukt.net/craft/socialize

Its in private beta and I haven't tried it but it seems to have a lot of the features we would need.

The big option questions would be how to manage any group messaging features but maybe you just have a "posts" channel that users can post to?

**Muut** https://muut.com/

Allows for an iframe type integration. Seems to be pretty full featured but wouldnt really share any data (or logins) with craft, would be a visual integration only

Any other options

We aren't looking for a ton of features, just a way for people to login, share text and photos, and comment on those posts.

Curious if anyone out there has tackled a problem like this?

Answer (score 3):

Out side of what you have mentioned, I recall [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) being mentioned on the Google+ Community. That's written in Ruby, though.

[Vanilla Forums](http://vanillaforums.org/) is open-source and written in PHP. It's also comes with SSO (Single-Sign On), and can be embedded into another site via an iframe.

There are currently no announced forum plugins native to Craft.

Comment: We have successfully used Vanilla and enabled SSO with Craft. Works well.

Comment: Hey dan,
I am working on embedding vanilla which i have managed to do with SSO working just fine. Next i want vanilla to assign the roles automatically as well as defined in my craft website. The permissions are going to be based on these roles. Is there any way I can pass user groups to vanilla from the jsConnect plugin such that it appropriately sets the user's role?

Answer (score 2):

Muut's Small subscription ($36/month if paid yearly, $45 if paid month to month -- previously $16/$20 for a 'developer subscription') includes 'Single Sign On', so users in Craft can translate to users in Muut without having to login a second time.

[BurnZone](http://www.theburn-zone.com/) is another alternative, similar to Disqus, it's tailored to commenting. You'd have to have a user create an entry, then use BurnZone/Disqus to facilitate comments on that entry. Both Disqus and BurnZone have 'Single Sign On' included as a free feature.

Answer (score 1):

The [Simple Machines Forum](https://www.simplemachines.org/) (SMF) is pretty good as far as forums go, comparing favorably to PHPBB. I've used Craft's bootstrapping capability to integrate Craft templates into SMF templates pretty easily:

```
// Bootstrap Craft
$craft = include '/path/to/craft/app/bootstrap.php';

// Save the output of the specified Craft template
$header = $craft->templates->render('includes/header');

// Show the saved output
echo $header;
```

I guess that holds for any PHP-based forum, of course.

It doesn't cover SSO, though.