# Displaying Craft templates in external apps

Tags: templating

I'm working on a site that is running Craft v2 and also has an installation of Simple Machines Forum (SMF). This has been fine using the approach outlined in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/23665/35), i.e.

```
$craft = include '/craft/app/bootstrap.php';
echo $craft->templates->render('includes/nav');
```

Now the site is being upgraded to v3 and this isn't working anymore. I've tried this:

```
$craft = include '/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
echo Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('includes/nav');
```

but with that I get:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'craft\services\Config' not found in /craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php on line 165

What else is missing to get this to work for Craft 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look into Craft's `index.php` file. It sets some constants, autoloads Composer dependencies and loads the environment file before actually loading the script that you tried. Here is the snippet:

```
<?php
/**
 * Craft web bootstrap file
 */

// Set path constants
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH', CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/vendor');

// Load Composer's autoloader
require_once CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/autoload.php';

// Load dotenv?
if (class_exists('Dotenv\Dotenv') && file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH.'/.env')) {
    Dotenv\Dotenv::create(CRAFT_BASE_PATH)->load();
}

// Load and run Craft
define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', getenv('ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production');
$app = require CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
$app->run();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. :)